# ReferenceError: Promise is not defined

Tags: node.js, git, server, nodes

after pushing my data , i am trying to use from another server git.pull('site','site') but i get this Error.

```
 ReferenceError: Promise is not defined
at deferred (/root/home/flash/Site/node_modules/simple-git/src/util/deferred.js:4:20)
at Git._schedule (/root/home/flash/Site/node_modules/simple-git/src/git.js:1363:23)
at Git._run (/root/home/flash/Site/node_modules/simple-git/src/git.js:1346:12)
at Git.pull (/root/home/flash/Site/node_modules/simple-git/src/git.js:337:19)
at port (/root/home/flash/Site/server.js:588:11)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/root/home/flash/Site/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at next (/root/home/flash/Site/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
at Route.dispatch (/root/home/flash/Site/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/root/home/flash/Site/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at /root/home/flash/Site/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
```

how to pull my data ??

*Note : When I type the command manually in the console it works (git pull site site) .

can someone help me please to solve this problem.

Comment: What version of node are you running? Maybe you need a promise polyfill?

Comment: Install promise using: npm install promise

Comment: i have node v0.10.40 , and promise 2.0.6 @evolutionxbox

Comment: `v0.10.40`? That version is almost 5 years old. Consider upgrading to a version which natively supports promises?

Comment: Thank you all , the problem was version , when upgrading the new version and now it`s work .  @evolutionxbox

Comment: @AhmadRweashd consider answering the question with that =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to install promise using cli:

```
npm install promise
```

Then add this to your code:

```
var Promise = require('promise');
```

For more detail go to: https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodegit-promise

Comment: i have var Promise = require('promise');  ,  it`s not working

Comment: Have you installed packages in server: You can do that by cli command: npm i

Comment: i do that , but the error steel   , i am doing a right command of pull, git.pull('site','site') , or i have to do something else with promise ??

Comment: upgrade your node.